# Tomcat stops working when more than 250-300 user are connected

Tags: java, tomcat

I  have one java application running on linux server.
when number of active sessions are exceeded after 250 tomcat does not worked?
I have following setting in tomcat setting file:

maxActive=1024 , session time out = 10 min  ----> in context file
maxThreads=1024  ----->in server.xml

Is there any other setting for tomcat?
Please give me solution for this .....
I am stuck with this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: shouldn't it be a question for ServerFault?

Comment: I suppose you have quite a bit of database access which could be the bottleneck.
Also list the version you use and the connector type (i.e. the standard or NIO). NIO would quite a better solution if server a lot of static content.

Comment: What are the symptoms of 'does not worked'?

Comment: Do you know whether it is exactly 250 or about 250 (oops just read the title okay 250-300).

Comment: Have you checked the Java Virtual Machine memory setting, as Qwerky says, it might help if we knew what "does not work(ed)" means.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether other limits e.g. kernel settings like: max open files per user etc. are hit.

Comment: Hitting max open files is quite a notorious case with tons of IOExceptions (any wrapped ones too). That should be easily noticed.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check your database connection pool settings

Comment: thanks for your quick answer , I have database connection pool maximum process & maximum session count is 400  , still it is giving errors